# ActiveAdmin set menu false by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, menu, activeadmin

So in ActiveAdmin resource pages I can easily add `menu false` in order to hide the menu item for current resource. I've set up a static menu in the `initializers/active_admin.rb` so now I'd like to make `menu false` default to every page, is there a way to do this in the initializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone encounters this, I ended up monkeypatching `ActiveAdmin::Resource::Menu` module and I've overwritten the `include_in_menu?` method to always return `false`. Not my favorite solution but it worked after days of trying many things.